# Does every finite partition of a topological space have a finite refinement such that the closure of every block is a union of blocks?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space.  Call a partition $\pi$ of $X$ *compatible with the topology,* or just *compatible,* if the closure of each block is a union of blocks (in other words, closures of blocks are saturated with respect to $\pi).$

For example, a compatible finite partition $\pi$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is used [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/60/bowron/k14.html) to represent the Kuratowski closure-complement problem in $\mathbb{R}$ as a problem in the finite quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\pi.$

Question: Does every finite partition $\pi$ of an arbitrary topological space $X$ have a compatible finite refinement?

A while back I conjectured [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/276991/partitions-of-the-reals-such-that-closures-of-partition-elements-are-saturated) that every connected finite space $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/\pi$ for some compatible partition $\pi$ of $\mathbb{R}.$ I verified in an answer that this holds for all connected $X$ such that $|X|\leq5.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $X=\mathbb{N}$ with the topology such that $C$ is closed iff $x\in C$ implies $y\in C$ for all $y\geq x$.  Consider the partition $\pi$ consisting of the even numbers and the odd numbers.  Given any finite refinement $\rho$ of $\pi$, let $A$ be the block of $\rho$ with the largest least element; let $n$ be the least element of $A$.  Then $n+1\in\overline{A}$, but $n+1\not\in A$ since $n+1$ and $n$ have different parity.  Let $B\in\rho$ be such that $n+1\in B$.  By our choice of $A$, $n+1$ cannot be the least element of its block $B$, so there is some $m\in B$ such that $m<n$.  But then $m\not\in\overline{A}$, so $B$ intersects $\overline{A}$ but is not contained in it.  Thus $\rho$ is not compatible with the topology.

Comment: Obvious as this is, it might be good to write "$n+1$ cannot be the least element of its block $B$" so the reader doesn't wonder what $B$ is.